# Opening the URL in child window using the CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, chromium, webview2

In my WPF WebView2 control, I want to execute the `window.open("https://www.google.com")` from the main window to open the URL in the child window using the `CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested`. But the URL webpage is not getting displayed in the child window instance.

I am quite not sure what is wrong with my below piece of code:

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
  private async void btnOpenPopup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     await MainWebView2Instance.ExecuteScriptAsync("openPopup()");
  }

  private async void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
  {
    Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Deferral deferral = e.GetDeferral();
    MainWindow childWindow = new MainWindow();
    childWindow.Title = "Child Window";

    //Creating a new webview2 instance for the child window
    WebView2 childWebView2Instance = new WebView2();
    await childWebView2Instance.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);

    childWebView2Instance.Source = new Uri(e.Uri);

    childWindow.dockPanel.Children.Add(childWebView2Instance);

    e.Handled = true;
    deferral.Complete();
    childWindow.Show();
  }
```

JavaScript in HTML Page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function openPopup() {
            window.open("https://www.google.com ");
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out (or remove) the following line:

```
await childWebView2Instance.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
```

-- it's blocking. You aren't using `CoreWebView2Environment`, so it's usage is unnecessary. When you set the Source property for `childWebView2Instance`, it will implicitly initialize CoreWebView2.

**Update:**

The following code will open a child window when a link on a web page is clicked where the HTML of the web page is the following:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>

<head>
</head>

<script>
  function popuponclick()
  {
     my_window = window.open("https://www.google.com");
  }

</script>

<body>

  <div>
    <a href="javascript: popuponclick()">Open Popup Window</A>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
         ...

<wv2:WebView2 
Name="webView21"
CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted="webView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted" 
Source="http://127.0.0.1:80/index.html"/>

         ...
```

**webView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted** (MainWindow.xaml.cs)

```
private void webView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.Title + " - webView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted");
    webView21.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested;
}
```

**Add using statements to MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;
```

In `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, add another constructor which can be used to set the Source property for the WebView2 control. It should look like the following:

**Constructors**: (MainWindow.xaml.cs)

```
         ...

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public MainWindow(string url)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    webView21.Source = new Uri(url);
}

         ...
```

**CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested** (MainWindow.xaml.cs)

```
private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    CoreWebView2 cwv2 = (CoreWebView2)sender;

    Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Deferral deferral = e.GetDeferral();

    MainWindow childWindow = null;
    childWindow = new MainWindow(e.Uri);
    childWindow.Title = "Child Window";
    childWindow.Show();

    e.Handled = true;
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this doesn't seem to be fixing my problem.

Comment: Commenting out the code that I suggested solves the "blocking" issue, but still may not get you to your desired result. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.  Please add more detail and additional code. Does `window.open("https://www.google.com", "_self");` achieve your goal?

Comment: Thanks again but this doesn't help. I think I have written a minimum reproducible problem where all I want is to achieve is to display a url webpage in a child wpf window when a click is made on the web page of parent wpf window using the CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested.

Comment: Thanks for your updated solution, This works like a charm as the parent here can have multiple descendants and each descendant is able to maintain its own instance in the wpf window. Appreciate your help :)